# Oracle Functions - VARCHAR2 length error (PLS-00215)

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures

I've been messing around with this for about the last 2 hours, and can't seem to find anything helpful (I've read up on some solutions, but for me they aren't working). I have the following create function statement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetBatchApprovalEmail(net_id IN NUMBER)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  email_address VARCHAR2(255);

  CURSOR C1 IS
    SELECT T1.approve_email
      FROM LMS.LMS_STATUS_EMAIL T1
        WHERE T1.NET_ID = net_id
BEGIN

  OPEN C1;
  FETCH C1 into email_address;
  CLOSE C1;

  RETURN email_address;
END;
/
```

For some reason, upon executing this statement I get a

`PLS-00215 error (String length constraints must be in range(1 .. 32767))`.

I've been reading up and most have said to just declare a size for the `VARCHAR2`, but I've tried and it doesn't make a difference.

Does anyone have any ideas? PS I'm fairly new to `PL/SQL` so its possible other things aren't correct.

Comment: Please show the code that calls this function.  Is it in PL/SQL ? Does the function compile?  Not clear.

Comment: Give us a complete example of how you're calling this function - it could be something wrong with the calling PL/SQL block as there's nothing obviously wrong here. Also, can you give us the definition of the LMS.LMS_STATUS_EMAIL field

Comment: There is no code yet that calls this function. I'm just creating it for the first time and executing it directly against the database.

Comment: Show the code you're using to execute it, then.

Comment: I'm using a GUI editor to execute the above script (TOAD). When I go to execute within TOAD I receive this error.

Comment: The code you posted won't compile.  There is no semicolon after your `SELECT` and before the `BEGIN`.  Not your problem but your `WHERE` clause is undoubtedly wrong.  An unqualified `net_id` references the column in the table not the parameter so your query will return every row in `LMS_STATUS_EMAIL` where `net_id is not null`.  You'd either want to use the function name as the qualifier or you'd want to name the parameter something that won't conflict with a column name.  I would prefer to use anchored types (i.e. `lms_status_email.approve_email%type` rather than a fixed length).

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors to your function. Check below to understand those.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetBatchApprovalEmail(net_id IN NUMBER)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  email_address VARCHAR2(255);

  CURSOR C1(num number) IS           ---Using passed parameter to the cursor
    SELECT T1.approve_email
      FROM LMS.LMS_STATUS_EMAIL T1
        WHERE T1.NET_ID = num;  
BEGIN

  OPEN C1(net_id);   --- This is the ways to pass parameter to a cursor.

  FETCH C1 into email_address;

  CLOSE C1;

  RETURN email_address;
END;
```